# How to proceed in finding $c_2$ and(or) the eigen values, given the following relation, when solving for a 1D wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I have the following general solution when solving for a $X(x)$ in a 1D wave equation.

$X(x) = c_1.\cos(\sqrt\lambda.x) + c_2.\sin(\sqrt\lambda.x)$

Applying the first boundary condition $u(0,t) = -1$ yields $c_1 = -1$.

Now applying the second B.C $u(\pi,t) = 1$, I am stuck on the following

$1 = (-1).\cos(\sqrt\lambda.\pi) + c_2.\sin(\sqrt\lambda.\pi) $

How do I determine $c_2$ and (or) the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ ?

Comment: Your first equation does not make too much sense. You should have two variables, something like $x$ and $t$.

Comment: @Andrei, edited the question to provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1 = -\cos(\sqrt\lambda \pi) + c_2\sin(\sqrt\lambda\pi) $$
From here $$c_2=\frac{1+\cos(\sqrt\lambda \pi)}{\sin(\sqrt\lambda \pi)}\\=\frac{2\cos^2(\sqrt\lambda \pi/2)}{2\sin(\sqrt\lambda \pi/2)\cos(\sqrt\lambda \pi/2)}\\=\cot(\sqrt\lambda \pi/2)$$

Comment: does cot have a relationship similar to $0 = sin(n.\pi)$ ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot%28x%29 The first positive root of cotangent is $\pi/2$, then you go with a period of $\pi$. So if you want $c_2$ to be zero, you use $\lambda=\pm1,\pm9,\pm25,\pm49,...$

Comment: Thank you I ended up taking c2 = 1 which helped me to get a relation $1 = sin(p) - cos(p)$ relation where $p=\sqrt(\lambda)*n$. From there I got eigenvalues to come out as $\lambda_n = n^2/4$